# Can't start a WCF Service installed as a Windows Service

Tags: web-services, wcf

I created a service that basically exposes some methods to update a sql server database.

**I tested the service as a normal WCF Service (not a Windows Service) and it worked fine** (which tells me that the ServiceModel definition in App.config is ok)

**Then I turned it into a Windows Service**, I installed it using InstallUtil, and it installed fine. **But when trying to start it** in the Services console, I get this message "**The service WCFProductsWindowsService service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs**"

The solution that exposes the service is composed of two projects,

1. a class library that defines the service, the contract, and an ADO
   NET Entity Data Model to the database,
2. and a console application that exposes the service

[image]

The class that exposes the serice is:

```
public class ProductsWindowsService : ServiceBase {
    public ServiceHost serviceHost = null;
    public ProductsWindowsService() {
        ServiceName = "WCFProductsWindowsService";
    }

    public static void Main() {
        ServiceBase.Run(new ProductsWindowsService());
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args) {
        if (serviceHost != null) {
            serviceHost.Close();
        }
        serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ProductsServiceImpl));
        serviceHost.Open();
    }

    protected override void OnStop() {
        if (serviceHost != null) {
            serviceHost.Close();
            serviceHost = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I uploaded the simple project in [SkyDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/?gologin=1&mkt=es-ES#cid=228822BB183339A9&id=228822BB183339A9!234)

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not allow me to add a comment. 
This error "**The service WCFProductsWindowsService service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs**" indicates an exception is thrown.

I would check the event viewer to see the exception logged.

Does `ProductsServiceImpl` exists? I can't find it in your image or in your solution.

Comment: I saw the Event Log and it said that there was a configuration error. Indeed, the ConnectionString section was erroneous